# UISearchBar not moving with Tableview when scrolling down

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

UISearchBar is not moving with Tableview when scrolling down.

I don't want to separately place the scrollbar. Its a requirement.
Below is the code.

```
customSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
customSearchBar.delegate = self;
[customSearchBar sizeToFit];
objListTable.tableHeaderView = customSearchBar;
```

Comment: instead of tableHeaderView to put search bar on tableview, can we use something else. My guess is that tableHeaderView is not letting it scroll down. please correct if i am wrong/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to include a View and add UISearchbar on it, or else provide height of the Header view. By default its treats as 0.0.

If you want to use

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

the method allocate a View with height of default `UISeachBar`height. and add `UISearchBar`on it.

Or else add a `UIView` on your code with default `UISearchBar` height add `UISearchBar` on it. It will works as you expected.

Comment: how do we specify the height of header. I'm lost on this. Cant find the correct property.

Comment: Updated my answer, Please check it.

Comment: The height of a header isn't a property, it's a `UITableViewDelegate` (or DataSource, can't remember) callback.

Comment: so @GuyKogus: can u please specify the delegate method.

Comment: `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`
That would've taken you a whole 10 seconds to find yourself...